# What does "1 second short circuit protection" mean?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, protection, short-circuit

In the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.it/datasheet/2/468/R1SE-1710037.pdf) of R1SE DC-DC family I read:

> Short Circuit Protection (SCP)    below 100 mΩ    1 second

What does it mean?
After 1 second of short-circuit the device will burn? What kind of "protection" is this?

Comment: Gives enough time for the fuse to blow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be enough to charge up a DC filter capacitor on power-up or when a device is plugged in. Remember that a discharged capacitor appears like a short-circuit initially.

There's only so much you can fit into the tiny form factor. You can get a DC/DC converter that will survive a short-circuit for longer but it will probably be bigger.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Found https://www.cui.com/product/resource/pdp1-m.pdf that states continuous short-circuit protection, same dimensions.